# Segmentation fault when trying to receive pointer value in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I'm quite new to Qt and c++ but not new to programming at all. I am having trouble using pointers in my program. In my header file I have got the following private variable pointer assignment:

```
private:
    QString *currentFile;
```

In my program I have got a function that starts by copying the value of the currentFile pointer to another QString variable:

```
QString fileName = *currentFile;
```

However this immediately gives me segmentation fault when debugging. I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong.

The program runs just fine until I call the function that tries to get the vlue of the pointer. I figured it might be becuase the pointer was empty so I tried adding the following code to my constructer:

```
*currentFile = QString::null;
```

To assign a `null` value to the pointer value, however this just gave me the segmentation fault as soon as the constructer was called.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

**EDIT**

*more code*:

notepad.h:

```
class Notepad : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Notepad();

private slots:
    void open();
    void save();
    void saveAs();
    void quit();

private:
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
    QString *currentFile;
    QString *currentContents;
};
```

the function creating the error (void save()) in notepad.cpp:

```
void Notepad::save(){
    QString fileName = *currentFile;
    if(fileName != "")
    {
        QFile file(fileName);
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Could not write to file"));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            QTextStream stream(&file);
            QString editorContent = textEdit->toPlainText();
            currentContents = &editorContent;
            stream << editorContent;
            stream.flush();
            file.close();
        }
    }
    else
        saveAs();
}
```

Comment: More code. Also, don't use a pointer, you don't need it.

Comment: `*currentFile = QString::null` in the constructor dereferences an uninitialized pointer. If anything, this should have been `currentFile = QString::null`.

Comment: @eran: He is syntactically correct.  QString::null is an uninitialzed string, not a null pointer (see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#distinction-between-null-and-empty-strings).  However, you are correct in saying he's trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer, which is causing his seg fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably due to the fact, that you never allocated any storage for the string. The pointer just stores a memory address and if its value is initialized to 0 (or even worse to nothing and contains a completely undefined address), then it doesn't point to a valid string object and trying to use the memory it points to as a string object results in undefined behaviour (in your case a segfault).

So you first need to allocate memory for a string and construct the string using (probably in the surrounding object's constructor):

```
currentFile = new QString;
```

and later (when not needed anymore, e.g. in the surrounding object's destructor):

```
delete currentFile;
```

But as said in the comments, I really doubt that you need a pointer member. Why not just use a `QString` object as member. Or if you really need pointers, rather use some smart pointer (like `auto_ptr` or the new C++11 `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`).

With `QObject` derived types (widgets and the like) it's a different story and you rather should use pointers for them (and Qt handles deallocation for you, if used properly). But `QString` is (like strings usually are) a rather value-like type (similar to the builtin types) and in most cases doesn't have to be allocated dynamically.

Comment: Most Qt data types, including QString implement implicit sharing which makes it very efficient even when used as values. Also, Qt has its own set of smart pointers, which admittedly isn't going to be important in the upcoming years as C++11 becomes widely implemented (but right now they are a reasonable choice because you can avoid adding yet another dependency to your program, like Boost to provide smart pointers).

Answer (score 2):

In both cases:

```
QString fileName = *currentFile;
*currentFile = QString::null;
```

you dereference an unitialized pointer.

The 2nd assignment doesn't initialize pointer to NULL; what it does is: dereference currentFile pointer first and destroy the object it points to, and replace it with QString::null object.

QString::null is a special structure used by Qt to indicate uninitialized strings, but don't confuse it with NULL pointer.

You should initialize your pointer like this:

```
currentFile = new QString();
```

Comment: Don't forget the `delete currentFile` later on!

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use pointers at all in the code you provided.  So, try this instead (from the code before you provided your edit)

```
private:
    QString currentFile;
```

```
QString fileName = currentFile;
```

```
currentFile = QString::null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If currentFile is null then of course de-referencing it is going to crash.  Setting it to QString::null does not give you an empty string.  It gives you a null pointer.  What you want is something like this: currentFile = "";

Cat Plus also has a good point.  You don't need a pointer in the first place (for what you've shown us).

Comment: Could you perhaps briefly explain where it would be smart to use pointers?

Comment: @Simon: Where values and references are not enough to solve the problem. Default to not using pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the constructor:

```
currentFile = new QString();
```

and don't forget to delete it (for example in the destructor.):

```
delete currentFile;
```